# Creating uiviewcontroller dynamically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create UIViewController dynamically without creating a class or using Mainstoryboard.I want it to happen programatically.Is it possible?
I want to create UIViewControllers depending on the dynamic data.

Comment: `let viewController = UIViewController()` =) Please explain better and show us your try in code, to get more deep answer

Comment: ok.I will try this

Answer (score 32):

Yes, you can create a view dynamically, programmatically. I know you said you don't want to use a class, but you really have to. The key, though, is that you don't have to have this class hard code the UI, but rather build it dynamically.

So, you can subclass `UIViewController`, but pass it the data it needs to build the view dynamically and then implement the [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) method to do so. No NIB or storyboard scene is needed. Just create the `view` and build the subviews based upon your dynamic data. This is described in the legacy [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011381-CH101-SW1). (Please note that portions of that document no longer apply, notably al of the "unload" view discussion. But it does describe and illustrate the `loadView` process, which still works fine.)

The process for building a view for a view controller is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, one of the paths (the custom `loadView` method) bypasses the storyboard/NIB workflow. Note, if you go about this process, you are responsible for instantiating a `UIView` object and setting the `view` property of the view controller. Also, do *not* call `super.loadView()` in your implementation.

For example, if I wanted to just add a bunch of `UILabel` objects to the view, in Swift 3 you could do something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var strings: [String]!
    
    override func loadView() {
        // super.loadView()   // DO NOT CALL SUPER
        
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        for string in strings {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.text = string
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

And you could present it like so:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = ViewController()
    controller.strings = ["Hello world", "Foobar", "Baz"]
    show(controller, sender: sender)
}
```

(For Swift 2 renditions, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37964249/3).)

---

Having said this, I'm not sure why you're concerned about not using a NIB or storyboard. Just use a blank one. And then, you can again programmatically add your controls to the scene dynamically, but do it in `viewDidLoad`. It achieves the exact same effect as the above, but avoids using the fairly antiquated `loadView` technique and from having to instantiate and load the `view` property yourself.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, just a question, do we also need to avoid calling super in any other methods that are overridden? such as `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @Munib - You generally call `super` (in the spirit of Liskov substitution principle), except where the docs explicitly advise you not do so. This is one example. The `start` method in an asynchronous `Operation` subclass is another. But it's pretty rare that you don't want to call `super`, and they're very good about telling you where you should not do so.

Comment: `let controller = ViewController()`
Should read:
`let controller = DynamicViewController()`

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Fixed.