# ViewController Modal Presentation not appearing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller that is a child view controller of my window's root view controller.  That child view controller has a table view and when i select a row it tells the parent view controller to present a view controller modally.  The modal view controller, however, never appears.  I created a bare bones test view controller that just prints `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.  What I notice is that when I call `parentVC.present(testVC, animated:true, completion:nil)`, `viewDidLoad` is run, but `viewWillAppear` is not.  `viewWillAppear` is only then called when I interact with the UI in some way.  Whether tapping, panning, scrolling or whatever.

I've spent hours trying to debug this.  It doesn't seem like the main queue is blocked and I've reduced the problem to its bare bones.  The modally presented view controller's `viewWillAppear` is simply not called until I interact with the UI again.

What could be causing this symptom?

Comment: Should we be able to guess this without code?

Comment: you may have set this `parentVC.present(testVC, animated:true, completion:nil)` in dispatch asynch queue. Share your code.

Comment: @Rob main queue was the first thing i thought and checked for.. i threw that assert in for good measure and no exception.  its on the main thread.

Comment: @Rob no.  no.  just:
```
func present() {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        let vc = TestVC()
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: no.  i'm just constructing a test VC.  i wonder if what happens is the local `vc` goes out of scope?  though later on when i interact with the screen `viewWillAppear` is called so the `vc` was apparently not deallocated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151531/discussion-between-alex-bollbach-and-rob).

Answer (score 2):

In comments, you mention that you're instantiating your view controller with

```
let vc = TestVC()
```

where `TestVC` is presumably a (largely empty) `UIViewController` subclass.

A view controller needs a view created either via either storyboard scene (using `instantiateViewController`), a NIB or, in very rare cases, a view you create in `loadView` (which you shouldn’t be confused with `viewDidLoad`).

I’d suggest creating a storyboard scene (assuming you are using storyboards), give it a storyboard ID, and then use [`instantiateViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller):

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foo")
```

But just having a `UIViewController` subclass called `TestVC` and instantiating it with `TestVC()` won’t work.

---

In our discussion, you said you wanted to do this programmatically with no NIB nor storyboard. If so, use [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964249/1271826 for an example.